# Change date format of ipywidgets.DatePicker

Tags: python, datepicker, ipywidgets

How to change format of dates for DatePicker from ipywidgets? Default format is 'mm/dd/yyyy' and I want to set it to 'yyyy-mm-dd'?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more? Do you mean the display text in the DatePicker widget? The default for me appears as dd/mm/yyyy.

If you call the .value attribute of the widget, once a date has been chosen, you will get a `datetime` object.

Comment: yes, default text for me is also in dd/mm/yyyy format, but i want to change displayed text format to yyyy-mm-dd

Comment: @ac24, how comes your default format  is dd/mm/yyyy? I run Ipython in a PC with Greek country codes (i.e. the date is dd/mm/yyyy) and I get an English one (mm//dd/yyyy)!

Comment: Does it depend on browser? I am using Chrome.